# Tuples with same coordinate sum

Tags: co.combinatorics

Some $4$-tuples of positive real numbers $(a_1,b_1,c_1,d_1),\dots,(a_n,b_n,c_n,d_n)$ are given, with $$\sum_{i=1}^na_i=\sum_{i=1}^nb_i=\sum_{i=1}^nc_i=\sum_{i=1}^nd_i=3.$$ It is known that there exists a partition of $N=\{1,\dots,n\}$ into three sets $A_1,A_2,A_3$ such that $$\sum_{A_1}a_i=\sum_{A_2}a_i=\sum_{A_3}a_i=1.$$ Analogous statements hold for $b,c,d$. Is it always possible to partition $N$ into two sets $X,Y$ so that
$$\sum_X a_i,\sum_X b_i,\sum_Y c_i,\sum_Y d_i\geq 1?$$
When the last line has one $X$ and three $Y$'s, the answer is [positive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2951883/tuples-with-all-coordinates-summing-to-3).

Comment: You posted this question to m.se, and accepted an answer there, so why are you posting here? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2951883/tuples-with-all-coordinates-summing-to-3

Comment: The question is different. I've clarified.

Comment: Seems to be a simpler version of the following (unanswered) question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/308839/partition-of-4-tuples