# 4-tuples with close sums

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrepancy-theory

Some $4$-tuples of positive real numbers $(a_1,b_1,c_1,d_1),\dots,(a_n,b_n,c_n,d_n)$ are given, with all $a_i,b_i,c_i,d_i\leq 1$. Is it always possible to partition $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ into two subsets $X,Y$ so that at least $3$ of the following $4$ inequalities hold:

$$\left|\sum_Xa_i-\sum_Ya_i\right|\leq 1, \left|\sum_Xb_i-\sum_Yb_i\right|\leq 1$$
$$\left|\sum_Xc_i-\sum_Yc_i\right|\leq 1, \left|\sum_Xd_i-\sum_Yd_i\right|\leq 1$$

An affirmative answer here would imply one for this (unsolved) [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/308839/partition-of-4-tuples).

Comment: As you are asking for "3 out of 4", have you found an example where there is no partition such that all 4 inequalities hold?

Comment: Yes, for example $(1,1,0,0),(1,0,1,0),(0,1,1,0)$